# Create custom validation provider devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using devexpress 13.1 and I like to create a custom validation provider for a textbox

I try with this code

```
DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ConditionValidationRule containsValidationRule = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ConditionValidationRule();
containsValidationRule.ConditionOperator = DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ConditionOperator.GreaterOrEqual;
containsValidationRule.Value1 = '0';
containsValidationRule.ErrorText = "Veuillez saisir un valeur supérieur a zéro";
containsValidationRule.ErrorType = ErrorType.Warning;

CompareAgainstControlValidationRule compValidationRule = new CompareAgainstControlValidationRule();
compValidationRule.Control = txtStockMax;
compValidationRule.CompareControlOperator = CompareControlOperator.LessOrEqual;
compValidationRule.ErrorText = "Veuillez saisir un valeur inférieur au stock max";
compValidationRule.CaseSensitive = true;

dxValidationProvider1.SetValidationRule(txtStockMin, containsValidationRule);
dxValidationProvider1.SetValidationRule(txtStockMin, compValidationRule);
```

What I'm looking for is that the `txtStockMin` is `greaterOrEqual` than 0 and `txtStockMin` is `lessOrEqual` to `txtStockMax`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [DXValidationProvider](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsDXErrorProviderDXValidationProvidertopic) help-topic. This topic also contains a clear code-example on how to create any custom validation rule.